# How to support both IPv4 & IPv6 on Java

Tags: java, linux, networking, network-programming, ipv6

One of our Java program when started, it only listen on IPv6 (8080)

e.g.

```
# netstat -ntpl

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

The problem is it is not accessible from outside (except localhost), to solve this, I have this manually add

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

But this make the program is only for IPv4 network.

Is it possible to do something like the **sshd** as above, both support IPv4 and IPv6?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I suspect it's less a Java programming issue than an OS networking stack/OS network configuration issue:

> http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.help/2009-09/msg00087.html
>
> On some OSes, a single native TCP socket can listen to a port on both
>       IPv4 and IPv6 simultaneously. It is able to accept connections from
>       remote IPv4 and from remote IPv6 clients. On other OSes (such as WinXP)
>       an OS native socket CANNOT do that, but can only accept from IPv4 or
>       IPv6, not both. On those OSes, it is necessary to have two listen
>       sockets in order to be able to accept connections from both remote IPv4
>       and IPv6 clients, one socket to listen for IPv4 connections and one for
>       IPv6.

Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 handle dual stacks just fine; Windows XP not so much :)

You seem to be on Linux - most modern Linux desktops and servers also handle dual ipv4 ipv6 with no problem.

Here's a good article on interoperability:

- http://ntrg.cs.tcd.ie/undergrad/4ba2.02/ipv6/interop.html

You know how you can "turn off" IPV6 for your Java application: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

You can also force your server to use IPV6 like this: `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only`

This is arguably your best source:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/index.html

You should absolutely be able to accomplish what you want (at least at the Java programming level), unless you're limited by external network issues:

```
Nodes)      V4 Only  V4/V6  V6 Only
            -------  -----  -------
V4 Only     x        x   
V4/V6       x        x      x
V6 Only              x      x
```

PS:

Here's one more good link, which explains what's happening at the socket level.  It's not Java (it's C), but exactly the sample principles apply:

- [Accept connections from both IPv6 and IPv4 clients](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzab6/rzab6xacceptboth.htm)